# How to fit the number of equation in same line with the equation

Tags: equations, numbering, fit

I have a problem, I want to fit the number of equation in the same line with equation, and I confuse why there are two number of equation in one equation.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{resizegather}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Proposisi}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definisi}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\mtcontentsname\contentsname\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase\mtcontentsname}
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\center\bfseries}{\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}{0.5cm}{\large}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{1cm}{-1cm}{1cm}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,beforeskip=2pt,entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
    \onehalfspacing
    \frontmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \mainmatter
    \begin{gather}
    \left(\sum_{j=1}^2\dfrac{A(1,1,2,j)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^j}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1=\left(\left(\sum_{j=0}^{1}\dfrac{A=(1,0,2,j)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^j}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1\right)e^{2\sigma_y(3)}\nonumber\\
    \left(\dfrac{A(1,0,2,0)}{1+r(2,0)}+\dfrac{A(1,0,2,1)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1=\left(\left(\dfrac{A(1,1,2,1)}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\dfrac{A=(1,1,2,2)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1\right)e^{2(18\%)}\nonumber\\
    \left(\dfrac{0,4554}{1+r(2,0)}+\dfrac{0,4554}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1=\left(\left(\dfrac{0,4374}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\dfrac{0,4374}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1\right)1,433.\\
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

This is the result of my code:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure, that this is a mwe? ;) Please delete all the not needed code :)

Comment: Besides your question, you should pay attention to load only the packages that you need to avoid conflits and longer compilation time. For instance, I see that you load both graphics and graphicx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant, also based on `nccmath` and the `aligned` environment and deleting the last `\\`, but using the `fleqn` and `medsize` environments. `fleqn`  makes the equation inside this environment startg at the left margin (the distance from from the left margin of the starting point is adjustable  with an optional argument). I added some spacing improvements:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \onehalfspacing
    \frontmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \mainmatter

\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{equation}
\begin{medsize}
    \begin{aligned}[b]
    \Biggl(\sum_{j=1}^2\frac{A(1,1,2,j)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^j}\Biggr)^{\!\!-\frac{1}{2}}-1 &=\mleft(\Biggl(\sum_{j=0}^{1}\frac{A=(1,0,2,j)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^j}\Biggr)^{\!\!-\frac{1}{2}}-1\mright)e^{2\sigma_y(3)} \\
    \mleft(\frac{A(1,0,2,0)}{1+r(2,0)}+\frac{A(1,0,2,1)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))}\mright)^{\!\!-\frac{1}{2}}-1 &=\mleft(\mleft(\frac{A(1,1,2,1)}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\frac{A=(1,1,2,2)}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^2}\mright)^{\!\!-\frac{1}{2}}-1\mright)e^{2(18\%)} \\
    \mleft(\frac{0,4554}{1+r(2,0)}+\frac{0,4554}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))}\mright)^{\!\!-\frac{1}{2}}-1 &=\mleft(\mleft(\frac{0,4374}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\frac{0,4374}{1+r(2,0)(\sigma(2))^2}\mright)^{\!\!-\frac{1}{2}}-1\mright)1,433. \end{aligned}
\end{medsize}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
\Biggl(\sum_{j=1}^2\mfrac{A(1,1,2,j)}{1+r(2,0)\sigma^j(2)}\Biggr)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1
    & =\Biggl[\biggl(\sum_{j=0}^{1}\mfrac{A=(1,0,2,j)}{1+r(2,0)\sigma^j(2)}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1\Biggr]e^{2\sigma_y(3)}
                    \\
\biggl(\mfrac{A(1,0,2,0)}{1+r(2,0)}+\mfrac{A(1,0,2,1)}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1
    & =\Biggl[\biggl(\mfrac{A(1,1,2,1)}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\mfrac{A=(1,1,2,2)}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)^2}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1\Biggr]e^{2(18\%)}
                    \\
\biggl(\mfrac{0,4554}{1+r(2,0)}+\mfrac{0,4554}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1
   & =\Biggl[\biggl(\mfrac{0,4374}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)}\mfrac{0,4374}{1+r(2,0)\sigma(2)^2}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1\Biggr]1,433.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In comparison to your (non)MWE, the equation code differ in the following:

- instead `gather` is used `aligned` encapsulated into `equation` environment
- deleted is `\\` at lat equation line, which produce additional equation number below it
- instead `\dfrac` is used medium size fractional  `\mfrac` from the `nccmath` package (with this equations become slightly shorter and equation number has place in the same line with equation)
- for outer braces are used square brackets
- `left(` and `right` are replaced `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` or with `\Biggl[` and `\Biggr]`

Answer (score 4):

### Step 1: reproduce and solve the issue

The main issue, i.e., the equation numbers that are not aligned with the equations, is due to the fact that your equation is very long, so it goes out of the document's margins.

The fact that you have an extra number is because you put a double antislash after your last equation.

Here is a code that reproduces your issues:

```
\begin{gather}
    x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x=y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y\\
    x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x=y+y+y+y+y+y\\
    x=y\\
\end{gather}
```

resulting in

[image]

To solve it, you can use the *multlined* environment from the *mathtools* package.

MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

    \begin{gather}
        \begin{multlined}
            x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
            = y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y
        \end{multlined}\\
        \begin{multlined}
            x+x+x+x\\
            +x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x=y+y+y+y+y+y+y
        \end{multlined}\\
        x=y
    \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

### Step 2 : better alignment

You might want to align equations for better looking, readability, ethical/philosophical opinion...
To do so you have to use the *align* environment instead of *gather*.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{align}
    &\begin{multlined}
        x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x\\
        = y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y
    \end{multlined}\\
    &\begin{multlined}
        x+x+x+x\\
        +x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x=y+y+y+y+y+y+y
    \end{multlined}\\
    &x=y
\end{align}
```

and the corresponding result

[image]

As you can see I aligned the equations on the left with the & symbol.

Enjoy!